# Do Column Headers Exist in Row of Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is an example dataframe:

```
cols = ["report_suite", "ProductID", "Manufacturer", "Brand Manager", "Finish"]
data = [["rs_1", "ProductID", "Manufacturer", "Finish", np.nan], ["rs_2", 
"ProductID", "Manufacturer", "Brand Manager", "Finish"], ["rs_3", 
"Brand Manager", "Finish", np.nan, np.nan]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = cols)
```

What I want to do is have a pivot table with a boolean in each column for whether the column header is in the row of data (not including the `report_suite` column).  So the final output I want is this:

```
cols = ["report_suite", "ProductID", "Manufacturer", "Brand Manager", "Finish"]
data = [["rs_1", 1, 1, 0, 1], ["rs_2", 1, 1, 1, 1], ["rs_3",  0, 0, 1, 1]]
final_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = cols)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [185]: df.set_index('report_suite') \
            .apply(lambda x: x.eq(x.name)) \
            .astype(np.int8) \
            .reset_index()
Out[185]:
  report_suite  ProductID  Manufacturer  Brand Manager  Finish
0         rs_1          1             1              0       0
1         rs_2          1             1              1       1
2         rs_3          0             0              0       0
```

or

```
In [191]: df.set_index('report_suite') \
            .fillna('') \
            .apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(x.name)) \
            .astype(np.int8) \
            .reset_index()
Out[191]:
  report_suite  ProductID  Manufacturer  Brand Manager  Finish
0         rs_1          1             1              0       0
1         rs_2          1             1              1       1
2         rs_3          0             0              0       0
```

Comment: Actually, this isn't what I need, because this only works if the row data is in the same order as the column headers. I need to check if the column header is anywhere in the row of data.

Comment: @Hound, do you want to "one-hot-encode" a text? Can you make an example of your "raw data"?

Comment: Well, it is not exactly "one hot encoding" because the data in the column does not necessarily match the header. For example, in the second row all columns match the headers, but in the third row the first value "brand manager" matches the third column header.

Answer (score 0):

I used a dictionary approach , if you can figure out how to change the indexing of the dataframe , you are good to go

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cols = ["report_suite", "ProductID", "Manufacturer", "Brand Manager", "Finish"]
data = [["rs_1", "ProductID", "Manufacturer", "Finish", np.nan], ["rs_2", 
    "ProductID", "Manufacturer", "Brand Manager", "Finish"], ["rs_3", 
     "Brand Manager", "Finish", np.nan, np.nan]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = cols)


preprocessed_data = []
for item in data:
    item.pop(0)
    preprocessed_data.append(item)

wordSet = set(preprocessed_data[0]).union(set(preprocessed_data[1])).union(set(preprocessed_data[2]))

wordict1 = dict.fromkeys(wordSet,0)
wordict2 = dict.fromkeys(wordSet,0)
wordict3 = dict.fromkeys(wordSet,0)

for word in preprocessed_data[0]:
    wordict1[word] += 1

for word in preprocessed_data[1]:
    wordict2[word] += 1

for word in preprocessed_data[2]:
    wordict3[word] += 1

dframe = pd.DataFrame([wordict1 , wordict2 , wordict3])
```